# transform string in class instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to turn string into a class to instantiate an object. Example:

## A normal class:

```
class Rank:
     def __init__ (self):
         print ('obj created ...')
```

## Instantiating an object:

```
obj = Rank ()
```

## Turning str in class ...

```
rank = 'Rank ()'
obj = rank
```

Sorry my english

Answer (score 3):

try to use dict

```
class Rank:
     def __init__ (self):
         print ( 'obj created ...')

option = { 'rank': Rank }

obj = option['rank']

print 'init object'
obj()

init object
obj created ...
```

Comment: As far as I know, while eval/exec work most people will warn you against them due to possible implications. I recommend using this Answer and just parsing out the arguments if you get passed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice, but you can execute strings by using `exec()`.
For example:

```
rank = 'Rank()'
exec('obj = ' + rank)
```

`exec` treats its parameter as if it was the line itself. So it'll basically execute `obj = Rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval().

Example:

```
class Rank:
     def __init__ (self):
         print ( 'obj created ...')

print ( eval("Rank") )
```